# How to identify all tables used in a query/stored procedure

Tags: sql

I am looking for a SQL query that can look at any query or stored procedure and return all the databases, schemas, tables, and columns being used.

For example, let's say I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
    Product.ID, Product.Name, Sales.Price
FROM
    Database1.dbo.Product
LEFT JOIN 
    Database2.dbo.Sales ON Product.ID = Sales.ProductID
```

Ideally, I'm looking for a query that will look through the above query and return:

- `Database1` and `Database2` in a `Databases` column
- `dbo` in a `Schema` column
- `Product` and `Sales` in a `Table` column
- `ID`, `Name`, `Price` and `ProductID` in a `Columns` column

Answer (score 0):

If you create views or stored procedures for the queries, then sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities will list the dependencies on other database objects.

Also, you could take a look at the execution plan of the queries and then post-process that output to get close to what you're looking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735(v=sql.105).aspx is a starting point for the SHOWPLAN_ALL T-SQL command